# Bengali text font broken when add text on image using php

Tags: php, unicode

```
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$our_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('certificates/main.jpg');

$black_color = imagecolorallocate($our_image, 0, 0, 0);
$font_path = 'arial.ttf';
$text = 'সৌরভ দাস';
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES',"UTF-8");
$text = html_entity_decode($text,ENT_NOQUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
$font_size=50;
$angle=0;
$left=1500;
$top=1400;
$output = imagettftext($our_image, $font_size,$angle,$left,$top, $black_color, $font_path, $text);

$imgName = "BDCH-Certificate-maper-".$uid.".jpg";
imagejpeg($our_image, 'certificates/'.$imgName);
```

> The output always shows something like this.
>   [image] Moreover i tried through these fonts, **SolaimanLipi_29-05-06.ttf**, **Rajon_Shoily.ttf** and **kalpurush ANSI.ttf**. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML?  Does it have something like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any encode/decode functions.  No mb functions are needed.

Is there any need to convert to .jpg?  Why not simply output text?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your text to Unicode2Bijoy [You can now only use ANSI fonts]

```
<?php

   header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
   require 'Unicode2Bijoy.php'; // https://github.com/mirazmac/Unicode2Bijoy
   use mirazmac\Unicode2Bijoy;

   $im = imagecreatetruecolor(1920, 1080);

   $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
   imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 1919, 1079, $white);

   $text = Unicode2Bijoy::convert('সে তার সময় বন্ধুদের সাথে ভালোই কাটাছিলো।');
   $font = 'fonts/Li Sheikh Hasina ANSI V2.ttf';
    
   imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 100, 200, $black, $font, $text);
   imagejpeg($im);
   imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

> সে তার সময় বন্ধুদের সাথে ভালোই কাটাছিলো।

For More: https://github.com/mirazmac/Unicode2Bijoy

ANSI Fonts: https://lipighor.com